# how to compile pygame in python 3

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7, python-3.9, pygame2

I don't know exactly the Error of this code I didn't get any Error but my code doesn't execute.  when I ran my code just I saw the rect's code run and after runing just I saw yellow rectangel in screen, the code-related print text doesn't execute.
Actully def in this code I think didn't run and don't show any Error and also the print text in end of my code dosen't run

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
input_text = ''
typing = False


win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Type Speed Program")


def print_text(screen, massage, x, y, font_s, clr):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, font_s)
    text = font.render(massage, True, clr)
    screen.blit(text, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()


def get_sentence():
    t_f = open('new.txt').read()
    sentences = t_f.split("\n")
    sentence = random.choice(sentences)
    pygame.display.update()
    return sentence


def start_game():
    sentence_s = get_sentence()
    print_text = (win, sentence_s, 100, 250, 40, (255, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 0), (75, 300, 650, 50), 3)
    pygame.display.update()


start_game()


while True:
   # win.fill(red)
    win.fill(black, (75, 300, 650, 50))
    print_text(win, input_text, 80, 310, 35, (255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.button == 1:
                if (75 <= x <= 725) and (300 <= y <= 350):
                    typing = True
                    input_text = ''
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if typing:
                if event.key == K_RETURN:
                    print(input_text)
                if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                    input_text = input_text[:-1]
                else:
                    input_text += event.unicode

    print_text = (win, "Typing Speed", 120, 80, 80, (0, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Use `print_text(...)` instead of `print_text = (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the second last line:

```
print_text = (win, "Typing Speed", 120, 80, 80, (0, 255, 255))
```

There you overwrite your defined function (print_text) with a tuple,  and afterward, you call the tuple in the game loop.

Removing the  = solves the problem.

```
print_text(win, "Typing Speed", 120, 80, 80, (0, 255, 255))
```